# Tkinter - Changing label text via another function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I know that it's often [best practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213935/why-use-classes-when-programming-a-tkinter-gui-in-python) to write Tkinter GUI code using object-oriented programming (OOP), but I'm trying to keep things simple because I'm new to Python.

I have written the following code to create a simple GUI:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def ChangeLabelText():
    MyLabel.config(text = 'You pressed the button!')

def main():
    Root = Tk()
    MyLabel = ttk.Label(Root, text = 'The button has not been pressed.')
    MyLabel.pack()
    MyButton = ttk.Button(Root, text = 'Press Me', command = ChangeLabelText)
    MyButton.pack()
    Root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

[The GUI looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppWic.png)

I thought the text in the GUI (MyLabel) would change to "You pressed the button!" when the button is clicked, but I get the following error when I click the button:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elsey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/elsey/Documents/question code.py", line 6, in ChangeLabelText
    MyLabel.config(text = 'You pressed the button!')
NameError: name 'MyLabel' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You need an object reference to be able to access MyLabel

Comment: The simplest solution for your exact code would be to add `global MyLabel` to both functions.  But this quickly gets messy for multiple widgets.  At some point, one or more classes with widgets as attributes and commands as methods wins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyLabel` is local to `main()` so the way you can not access it that way from `ChangeLabelText()`.

If you do not want to change the design of your program, then you will need to change the definition of `ChangeLabelText()` like what follows:

```
def ChangeLabelText(m):
    m.config(text = 'You pressed the button!')
```

And withing main() you will need to pass `MyLabel` as an argument to `ChangeLabelText()`.

But again, you will have a problem if you code this `command = ChangeLabelText(MyLabel)` when you declare and define `MyButton` because the program will execute directly the body of `ChangeLabelText()` at the start and you will not have the desired result.

To resolve this later problem, you will have to use (and may be read about) [`lambda`](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk)

## Full program

So your program becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def ChangeLabelText(m):
    m.config(text = 'You pressed the button!')

def main():
    Root = Tk()
    MyLabel = ttk.Label(Root, text = 'The button has not been pressed.')
    MyLabel.pack()
    MyButton = ttk.Button(Root, text = 'Press Me', command = lambda: ChangeLabelText(MyLabel))
    MyButton.pack()
    Root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
  main()
```

## Demo

Before clicking:

[image]

After clicking:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. I'll mark this as the best answer, but I think I'll try use classes in my code.

Comment: I think this answer would be a tiny bit better if you didn't use wildcard imports. PEP8 discourages them.

Comment: Yes, you are very right. And you mentioned this recently through one of your comments to an other member too. I would also use classes but the OP says he is a beginner, so introducing him lambda and how to use a callback method with arguments is, I think, too much for a beginner already and may be it is too early to mention him PEPs. As it is commonly said, lot of information kills the information. But if you read below, I commented one of the answers to encourage the OP to use OOP and I upvoted both answers below. But again you are right @BryanOakley

Answer (score 2):

Are your sure you don't want to do it as a class (i think it makes the code a bit more clean as your project grows)? Here is a way to accomplish what you'e looking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class myWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.MyLabel = ttk.Label(root, text = 'The button has not been pressed.')
        self.MyLabel.pack()
        self.MyButton = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Press Me', command = self.ChangeLabelText)
        self.MyButton.pack()

    def ChangeLabelText(self, event=None):
        self.MyLabel.config(text = 'You pressed the button!')


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = Tk()
    mainWindow = myWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

In a Mac, is looks like this before pressing the button:

[image]

And when you press it:

[image]

But basically, in order to be able to change the text in a Label or a button, you need to ensure it has an active reference. In this case, we are doing it by creating the window as a class and referencing the widgets in the form `self. widget_name = widget()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

*but I'm trying to keep things simple because I'm new to Python*  Hopefully this helps in understanding that classes are the simple way, otherwise you have to jump through hoops and manually keep track of many variables. Also, the Python Style Guide suggests that CamelCase is used for class names and lower_case_with_underlines for variables and functions. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class ChangeLabel():
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        self.my_label = ttk.Label(root, text = 'The button has not been pressed.')
        self.my_label.pack()
        ## not necessary to keep a reference to this button
        ## because it is not referenced anywhere else
        ttk.Button(root, text = 'Press Me',
               command = self.change_label_text).pack()
        root.mainloop()

    def change_label_text(self):
        self.my_label.config(text = 'You pressed the button!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CL=ChangeLabel()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for bringing that style guide to my attention.

Comment: Yes, it is good to initiate yourself to object oriented concepts as shown in this good answer.